# Pyspark Convert row data to key value pairs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, key-value

I have a data file which looks like below:

```
([Fire Grilled Steak Bowl, Veri Veri Teriyaki Marinade & Sauce],1)
([Fat Free Strawberry Yogurt, Strawberry Banana Juice],1)
([Organic  Unsweetened & Salt Free Sunflower Seed Butter, Organic Broccoli Crowns],1)
([Roma Tomato, Vanilla Soymilk],3)
([15 Calories Light Lemonade, Lemon-Lime 12 Pack Soda],1)]
```

When I take this data and put it into an RDD like so,

```
data=sc.textFile("hdfs:\\h1:9000\data.txt")
data.collect()
```

the output is printed out like below

```
['([Fire Grilled Steak Bowl, Veri Veri Teriyaki Marinade & Sauce],1)', '([Fat Free Strawberry Yogurt, Strawberry Banana Juice],1)', '([Organic  Unsweetened & Salt Free Sunflower Seed Butter, Organic Broccoli Crowns],1)', '([Roma Tomato, Vanilla Soymilk],3)', '([15 Calories Light Lemonade, Lemon-Lime 12 Pack Soda],1)']
```

I am using pyspark and would like to convert this RDD into key value pairs, where the list `[item1,item2]` would be the key and the number after comma would be the value. When I try to access it as `x[0]` and `x[1]` I end up getting `(` and `[` respectively
It should be pretty simple, I don't understand how to get `x[0]=[item1,item2]` and `x[1]=num`.

Comment: Are you looking for `rdd.map(lambda row: (tuple(row[0]), row[1]))`?

Comment: @pault when I write  `rdd.map(lambda row:(tuple(row[0]), row[1])).take(5)` it gives me the output `[(('(',), '['), (('(',), '['), (('(',), '['), (('(',), '['), (('(',), '[')]` while I would like  `row[0]=[Fire Grilled Steak Bowl, Veri Veri Teriyaki Marinade & Sauce]` and `row[1]=1`

Comment: Your data is really stored *exactly* like that? The brackets and parentheses are there? No quotes around the text? The better question is how did it end up like that? Is it possible to fix the problem upstream somewhere? You could build a parser but it would be complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though your source data is stored in an inconvenient format. It's almost as if it was a printed tuple, but there are no quotes around the strings which prevent you from evaluating the line as an object.

However, from the sample you provided, it seems as if you can get the desired output by splitting on commas and stripping brackets.

After that  you can call `map()` and build your key-value pairs as desired.

```python
data = [
    '([Fire Grilled Steak Bowl, Veri Veri Teriyaki Marinade & Sauce],1)',
    '([Fat Free Strawberry Yogurt, Strawberry Banana Juice],1)',
    '([Organic Unsweetened & Salt Free Sunflower Seed Butter, Organic Broccoli Crowns],1)',
    '([Roma Tomato, Vanilla Soymilk],3)',
    '([15 Calories Light Lemonade, Lemon-Lime 12 Pack Soda],1)'
]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

rdd.map(lambda row: map(lambda x: x.strip().strip("[]()"), row.split(",")))\
    .map(lambda row: ((row[0], row[1]), int(row[2]))).collect()
```

Which prints:

```python
[(('Fire Grilled Steak Bowl', 'Veri Veri Teriyaki Marinade & Sauce'), 1),
 (('Fat Free Strawberry Yogurt', 'Strawberry Banana Juice'), 1),
 (('Organic Unsweetened & Salt Free Sunflower Seed Butter', 'Organic Broccoli Crowns'), 1),
 (('Roma Tomato', 'Vanilla Soymilk'), 3),
 (('15 Calories Light Lemonade', 'Lemon-Lime 12 Pack Soda'), 1)]
```

This assumes that there are exactly 3 commas on each line. If there are any commas in the text, this method will not work. If that assumption is not valid, then my recommendation is to modify the program that is generating these files to produce a friendlier format.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I think your suggestion works. The data is exactly in that format because some other program produces it.